# class's friend function are incompatible?

Tags: c++

IDE throws warning that the class's friend function are not compatible with the function's declaration outside of class.
What is the cause for the warning?

```
namespace CommonUtility
{
    Interface::CellType Foo(int);
}

// when placed as friend of class Interface
class Interface
{
public:
    static enum class CellType
    {
        Group,
        NoSuchType
    };
    friend Interface::CellType CommonUtility::Foo(int); // IDE warning not compatible to the declaration 
}

// definition
Interface::CellType CommonUtility::Foo(int i)
{
  if (i == 1)
   return Interface::CellType::Group;
  else
   return Interface::CellType::NoSuchType;
}
```

Comment: Which warning ? Error messages often give you the right information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. For `Interface::CellType Foo(int);` the `Interface::CellType` is unknown at that point and should result in a compiler error.
2. `static enum class CellType` would also result in a compiler error, because `static` is not correct here.

And finally:

The declaration of `Interface::CellType CommonUtility::Foo(int);` has to exists before `friend Interface::CellType CommonUtility::Foo(int);` can be used. But `Interface::CellType Foo(int);` can only be declared as soons as `Interface::CellType` is known.  `CellType` is a nested type and cannot be forward decaled.

And these conditions conflict with each other.

You would need to move the whole `enum class CellType {}` outside of `class Interface` to get that working.